# How do I pull a number of words around a specific word in python?

Tags: python

So I need a simple way to pull ten words from before and after a search term in a paragraph, and have it extract all of it into a sentence.

example:

> paragraph = 'The domestic dog (Canis lupus familiaris or Canis familiaris) is a member of genus Canis (canines) that forms part of the wolf-like canids, and is the most widely abundant carnivore. The dog and the extant gray wolf are sister taxa, with modern wolves not closely related to the wolves that were first domesticated, which implies that the direct ancestor of the dog is extinct. The dog was the first domesticated species and has been selectively bred over millennia for various behaviors, sensory capabilities, and physical attributes.'

input

> > wolf

output

> > most widely abundant carnivore. The dog and the extant gray wolf are sister taxa, with modern wolves not closely related to

Answer (score 4):

```
paragraph = 'The domestic dog (Canis lupus familiaris or Canis familiaris) is a member of genus Canis (canines) that forms part of the wolf-like canids, and is the most widely abundant carnivore. The dog and the extant gray wolf are sister taxa, with modern wolves not closely related to the wolves that were first domesticated, which implies that the direct ancestor of the dog is extinct. The dog was the first domesticated species and has been selectively bred over millennia for various behaviors, sensory capabilities, and physical attributes.'
word = "wolf"
wordlist = paragraph.split(" ")

index = wordlist.index(word)
first_part = wordlist[index-10:index]
second_part = wordlist[index:index+11]
print("%s %s" % (" ".join(first_part), " ".join(second_part)))
```

Output:

```
most widely abundant carnivore. The dog and the extant gray wolf are sister taxa, with modern wolves not closely related to
```

Comment: Granted this is simple, you are going to run into performance issue with large bodies of text.

Answer (score 2):

This is the regular expression that may help you extract the desired text:

```
(?:[^ ]+ ){0,10}wolf(?: [^ ]+){0,10}
```

also a python example should go like, though I can't test it now:

```
import re

t = "The domestic dog (Canis lupus familiaris or Canis familiaris) is a member of genus Canis (canines) that forms part of the wolf-like canids, and is the most widely abundant carnivore. The dog and the extant gray wolf are sister taxa, with modern wolves not closely related to the wolves that were first domesticated, which implies that the direct ancestor of the dog is extinct. The dog was the first domesticated species and has been selectively bred over millennia for various behaviors, sensory capabilities, and physical attributes"

m = re.search("(?:[^ ]+ ){0,10}wolf\s(?:[^ ]+ ){0,10}", t)

if m:
    print (m.group(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using substring after finding the position of the target word. Have you tried to code anything so far?